# Why hasn't my variable changed after applying a bit-shift operator to it?

Tags: c++, bitwise-operators

```
int main()
{
    int i=3;
    (i << 1);
    cout << i; //Prints 3
}
```

I expected to get 6 because of shifting left one bit. Why does it not work?

Comment: Wow a lot of people are on-line tonight

Comment: His question brings all the programmers to the yard?

Comment: If you didn't get a compiler warning, you probably aren't using enough flags on your compilations.  You should be told about 'statement with no effect' on the left-shift line, though somewhat to my surprise, G++ 4.6.0 did not complain about that - though when I rewrote it in C, GCC 4.6.0 did complain.

Comment: You could get nicely confused by the difference between `cout << i << 1 << endl;` and `cout << (i << 1) << endl;` (and don't forget to put a newline at the end of your output).

Comment: @Victor We usually get only an hour a day in the yard.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Because the bit shift operators return a value.

You want this:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
     int i = 3;
     i = i << 1;
     std::cout << i;
}
```

The shift operators don't shift "in place". You might be thinking of the other version. If they did, like a lot of other C++ binary operators, then we'd have very bad things happen.

```
i <<= 1; 

int a = 3;
int b = 2;
a + b;    // value thrown away
a << b;   // same as above
```

Answer (score 10):

You should use `<<=` or the value is just lost.

Answer (score 4):

You need to assign `i` to the shifted value.

```
int main()
{
    int i=3;
    i <<= 1;
    cout << i; //Prints 3
}
```

Alternatively, you can use <<= as an assignment operator:

```
i <<= 1;
```

Answer (score 4):

You're not assigning the value of the expression `(i << 1);` back to `i`.

Try:

```
i = i << 1;
```

Or (same):

```
i <<= 1;
```

Answer (score 3):

Because you didn't assign the answer back to i.

```
i = i << 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to reassign the value back to `i` with `i<<=1` (using "left shift and assign operator")

Answer (score 2):

**Reason:**
`i << 1` produce an intermediate value which is not saved back to variable `i`.

```
// i is initially in memory
int i=3;

// load i into register and perform shift operation,
// but the value in memory is NOT changed
(i << 1);

// 1. load i into register and perform shift operation
// 2. write back to memory so now i has the new value
i = i << 1;
```

For your intention, you can use:

```
// equal to i = i << 1
i <<= 1;
```