# Bitshift on assignment has no effect on the variable

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bit-shift

I thought I'd found something similar in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6367379/why-hasnt-my-variable-changed-after-applying-a-bit-shift-operator-to-it) but in that case they weren't assigning the result of the expression to the variable. In my case I am assigning it but the bitshift part of the expression has no effect.

```
unsigned leftmost1 = ((~0)>>20);
printf("leftmost1 %u\n", leftmost1);
```

Returns

```
leftmost1 4294967295
```

Whereas

```
unsigned leftmost1 = ~0;
leftmost1 = leftmost1 >> 20;
printf("leftmost1 %u\n", leftmost1);
```

Gives me

```
leftmost1 4095
```

I would expect separating the logic into two lines would have no impact, why are the results different?

Comment: @M.M Edited for clarity

Comment: Your implementation is shifting in a `1` bit to a signed value that already has all bits set to `1`. So no change. Too many answers now ahead of my `(~0u)>>20`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the first case, you are doing a *signed right shift*, because `~0` results in a signed value. The exact behavior of signed right shifts is implementation-defined, but most platforms, including yours, extend the sign bit, so the shift is a no-op for your input of "all ones".

In the second case, you are doing an unsigned right shift, since `leftmost1` is an `unsigned` value. So you shift in zeros from the left.

If you wanted to do an unsigned shift without the intermediate assignmetn, you can do:

```
(~0u) >> 20
```

Where the `u` suffix indicates an unsigned literal.

Comment: Fair enough, but outside of language-lawyering those aren't opposites. I meant "unspecified by the standard".

Comment: The standard does specify , and it specifies that the implementation must document its choices. This is an important difference from saying that the behaviour could be effectively random.

Comment: Even if correct, you are being pedantic: my point is that the standard doesn't _specify the exact behavior_, and requires the implementation to _specify_ it. Maybe you call that "specified behavior" but it's just semantics - to me it is correct to say "it is not specified in the standard". Yes I understand this is different from _UB_ or something which isn't even mentioned in the standard.

Answer (score 3):

`~0` is an `int`.  So your first piece of code isn't equivalent to the second, it's equivalent to

```
int tmp = ~0;
tmp = tmp >> 20;
unsigned leftmost1 = tmp;
```

You're seeing the results of sign extension when you right-shift a negative number.

Answer (score 2):

Try casting like this.  ~0 is <s>promoted to</s> int which is signed so it's carrying the sign bit when you shift

```
unsigned leftmost1 = ((unsigned)(~0)>>20);
printf("leftmost1 %u\n", leftmost1);
```

Comment: `~0` and `0` are both already of type int and no promotion happens. Your version is not completely correct, the cast should be done before the bitwise not.

Comment: @2501 it's the shift operation that's causing the problem.  My version results in an unsigned or logical right shift.

Comment: Your answer says that ~0 is promoted to int, but that is not correct, as the type of 0 is already int.

Answer (score 2):

`0` has type `int`. `~0` is `-1` on a typical two's complement machine. Right-shifting a negative number has implementation-defined results, but a common choice is to shift in `1` bits, which for `-1` leaves the number unchanged (i.e. `-1 >> anything` is `-1` again).

You can fix this by writing `0u` (which is a literal of type `unsigned int`). This forces the operations to be done in `unsigned int`, as in your second example:

```
unsigned leftmost1 = ~0;
```

This line is equivalent to `unsigned leftmost1 = -1`, which implicitly converts -1 (a signed int) to `UINT_MAX`. The following operation (`leftmost1 >> 20`) then uses unsigned arithmetic.